# Oracle left join with conditions from the target table

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have two tables **Customers**, **Sales** like below:

**Customers** :

| id | first_name | last_name | gender | age | customer_since |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Daniel | Black | M | 34 | 2014-10-13 |
| 2 | Erik | Brown | M | 25 | 2015-06-10 |
| 3 | Diana | Trump | F | 39 | 2015-10-25 |
| 4 | Anna | Yao | F | 19 | 2017-02-20 |
| 5 | Christian | Sanders | M | 42 | 2018-01-31 |

**Sales**:

| id | date | book_id | customer_id | quantity | amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2019-09-02 | 2 | 3 | 1 | 14.99 |
| 2 | 2019-10-01 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 12.99 |
| 3 | 2019-10-01 | 3 | 4 | 1 | 15.75 |

I need to get all customers and their data in sales table even if they don't have records in sales table so I did left join like below :

```
SELECT c.id as customer_id, c.first_name, c.last_name, c.gender, c.age, c.customer_since,    
       s.sdate AS sales_date, s.id as sale_id
FROM customers c
LEFT JOIN sales s
ON c.id = s.customer_id
```

and I got this result:

| CUSTOMER_ID | FIRST_NAME | LAST_NAME | GENDER | AGE | CUSTOMER_SINCE | SALES_DATE | SALE_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | Diana | Trump | F | 39 | 25-OCT-15 | 02-SEP-19 | 1 |
| 2 | Erik | Brown | M | 25 | 10-JUN-15 | 01-OCT-19 | 2 |
| 1 | Daniel | Black | M | 34 | 13-OCT-14 | - | - |
| 4 | Anna | Yao | F | 19 | 20-FEB-17 | - | - |
| 5 | Christian | Sanders | M | 42 | 31-JAN-18 | - | - |

which is expected my question is what if I need to get all customers that only in the source table and customers from the target table which has specific condition I run the below query

```
SELECT c.id as customer_id, c.first_name, c.last_name, c.gender, c.age, c.customer_since,    
       s.sdate AS sales_date, s.id as sale_id
FROM customers c
LEFT JOIN sales s
ON c.id = s.customer_id
where s.id=1
```

and I got only one record like this

| CUSTOMER_ID | FIRST_NAME | LAST_NAME | GENDER | AGE | CUSTOMER_SINCE | SALES_DATE | SALE_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | Diana | Trump | F | 39 | 25-OCT-15 | 02-SEP-19 | 1 |

but I need this result

| CUSTOMER_ID | FIRST_NAME | LAST_NAME | GENDER | AGE | CUSTOMER_SINCE | SALES_DATE | SALE_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | Diana | Trump | F | 39 | 25-OCT-15 | 02-SEP-19 | 1 |
| 1 | Daniel | Black | M | 34 | 13-OCT-14 | - | - |
| 4 | Anna | Yao | F | 19 | 20-FEB-17 | - | - |
| 5 | Christian | Sanders | M | 42 | 31-JAN-18 | - | - |

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move the criteria from the `WHERE` clause of the second query to the `ON` clause of the join:

```sql
SELECT c.id as customer_id, c.first_name, c.last_name, c.gender, c.age,
       c.customer_since, s.sdate AS sales_date, s.id AS sale_id
FROM customers c
LEFT JOIN sales s
    ON c.id = s.customer_id AND s.id = 1;
```

By restricting the sales ID in the `WHERE` clause, you filter off any non matching records.  By moving this restriction to the join, all records would be retained, but `NULL` values would appear for all non matching sales fields.

Comment: I just have one question for you can we use this using (+) shortcut ? or we must use teh full left join keyword to achieve this ?

Comment: The syntax I have used above is ANSI-92 compliant and is the preferred way to write the query.  Forget about doing outer joins with `+`; practically nowhere is this syntax used in modern systems.